# Homomorphisms between non-isomorphic finite lattices

Tags: lattice-theory

Let $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ be non-isomorphic finite lattices of the same cardinality. Can there exist any lattice homomorphisms between $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$?

Comment: Yes, but you probably mean to ask a different question. There are constant maps, and in some cases maps to a two element interval.  It depends (partly) on what congruences each lattice has.  Gerhard "Maybe Your Lattices Are Special?" Paseman, 2018.08.04.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman are constant maps lattice homomorphisms?

Comment: I assume lattice means algebraic structure, and he did not specify bounds. Yes the constant map preserves the algebraic relations, as the functions are idempotent.  Gerhard "This Is What I Understand" Paseman, 2018.08.04.

Comment: Ah, I was assuming the top and bottom elements should be preserved. Probably I'm mistaken about what the standard terminology is.

Comment: Of course, given an example which doesn't preserve top and bottom, one can simply adjoin new top and bottom elements to both lattices to obtain an example which does preserve top and bottom.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman, thanks this is helpful. I overlooked the constant maps which, as you point out, preserve the algebraic relations and can be extended to preserve bounds in an obvious way. I'm not sure what you mean about the two element interval case though? Could you please elaborate? And are these the only kinds of homomorphism there can be in this setting?

Comment: @TobiasFritz, thanks for the comment, but I'm not sure I get the implication. All finite Boolean algebras of the same cardinality are isomorphic, so I didn't think the Boolean cases would be pertinent here. What am I missing?

Comment: OK then finite distributive lattice duality gives bijection between (bounded) lattice homomorphisms ${\downarrow}P\to{\downarrow}Q$ and order preserving maps $Q\to P$, for finite posets $P$, $Q$. You can take e. g. two element discrete poset for $Q$ and a three element chain for $P$; all maps from $Q$ to $P$ are order preserving, while both ${\downarrow}P$ and ${\downarrow}Q$ have four elements (one is a chain and another a Boolean algebra).

Comment: There are lattices (most of them not simple) which admit homomorphisms onto the two element lattice. These lattices thus have (not quite) n choose 2 many additional homomorphisms into an n element lattice. It is easy to show a lower bound of 2n-3 on the number of these kinds of maps.  One can find other maps depending on the lattices involved. Again, you might consider asking this on a different forum, or show more motivation and background. As it is, these questions need more to fit well into this forum.  Gerhard "Good Question But Poor Fit" Paseman, 2018.08.04.

Comment: @BenEva: sorry, I had misunderstood the question.